# How to identify the USB camera in Windows?

Tags: qt, opencv, webcam

I am looking for the physical id of the camera to identify the device by Windows API(or OpenCV/Qt API any possible solution in Windows platform).

Eg. There is two same use camera which has the same brand and type. So I need to identify the captured image is from which one.

If identify camera is impossible, How about detecting the camera is using which USB port?

BTW is possible to physically modify the PID/VID/Name of the camera?

Update:

I couldn't find the solution...so pay the USB camera manufacturer and ask them to modify the PID to the specified ID.